# The point of using 'var' when code works without its use?

Tags: javascript, var

Why do we use the keyword: 'var' when the code works very well without using it.

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = compare;


function compare() {
     cool = "45";     
     alert(cool +1)    // I can alert it or do anything else without using 'var'
}
```

Here, a string is stored in 'cool' and I can do anything with it as if it was a variable. Isn't it a variable here? If it is, then what difference does the keyword 'var' makes?

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you omit the `var` keyword you're doing an "implicit declaration". This is not recommended as this type of declaration has global scope. If you want a locally scoped variable you need to use the `var` keyword.